# Save settings value accessible globally in KODI

Tags: python, xbmc, kodi

I'm writing Multiple Add-ons for a personal build of KODI.
What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Service(Add-on A) will authenticate the box using its MAC Address.
2. Service(Add-on A) will save a token(T1).
3. Service(Add-on B) will use T1 and load movies if (T1 != None)

BUT
xbmcplugin.setSetting( "token" ) AND xbmcplugin.getSetting( "token" ) saves the value in the context of Add-on where it was called.

HOW to achieve Saving Global Values in KODI with Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window properties for that. Window 10000 is one of the main windows so it will always exist.

Set it
`xbmcgui.Window(10000).setProperty('myProperty', 'myValue')`

Read it
`xbmcgui.Window(10000).getProperty('myProperty')`

Comment: This works perfectly fine for Strings. 
How to save Booleans? I need to use boolean in my skin saved by a Service.

Comment: Well as long as you control it, you can just equal a string and take that bool for whatever you want to do. I'm not aware of datatypes in the property department.